# Assert MSSQL stored procedure execution time with tSQLt

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

I want to create SQL unit tests to measure the execution time of my stored procedures. Is there a way to assert the duration time of each execution?

**Solution i am using finally:**

--run my stored procedure

```
exec mySP
```

--Get the metrics

```
  SELECT d.object_id, d.database_id, OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) 'proc name',   
    d.cached_time, d.last_execution_time, d.total_elapsed_time,  
    d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],  
    d.last_elapsed_time, d.execution_count  
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d  
where OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) = 'mySP'
ORDER BY [total_worker_time] DESC;
```

--Rum my assertions based on `last_elapsed_time` and `avg_elapsed_time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at <kbd>[sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx)</kbd> available from SQLServer 2008..this DMV provides some usefull info like

[image]

You also can look at SET STATISTICS TIME ON  as well

```
set statistics time on
exec usp_test
set statistics time off
```

You can see time in messages tab like below

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 171 ms,  elapsed time = 5060 ms.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps.